# How to remove empty tags

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-replace

I'm using Summernote plugin, so whenever i write anything it keeps on creating empty tags like this

```
<b><br></b><br></p><br><p><b><br></b><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

How can i remove these empty tags as these tags take whole blank space in the page

Here is what I've tried till now

```
function remove_empty_tags_recursive ($str, $repto = NULL)
{
    //** Return if string not given or empty.
    if (!is_string ($str)
        || trim ($str) == '')
            return $str;

    //** Recursive empty HTML tags.
    return preg_replace (

        //** Pattern written by Junaid Atari.
        '/<([^<\/>]*)>([\s]*?|(?R))<\/\1>/imsU',

        //** Replace with nothing if string empty.
        !is_string ($repto) ? '' : $repto,

        //** Source string
        $str
    );
}
```

This above function only filters those tags which are like `<p></p>`
This doesn't filter `<p><br></p>`

I have found this article also [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) but it is completely different as it about finding particular tag

Comment: [DON'T EVER USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2397327)

Comment: @Isaac Haha that happened to be the same post I linked to

Comment: I recommend using http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: You shouldn't try to band-aid the effects of an improper page generator. Find what is creating those empty elements and add `if` conditions that omit them altogether if their content is going to be empty. Fix the cause, not the symptoms.